How do transaction and non-transaction updates affect the same entity?
I have an entity that has a sum field and I read the entity, update the sum and then save the entity, all inside of a transaction.
What would happen if at the same time the entity is being updated in a transaction, somewhere else in the application, that same entity was read, updated and saved but NOT in a transaction?
Here is a theoretical order of events:
Entity A has a sum of 1

Transaction: query Entity A
Non-transaction: query Entity A
Transaction: update Entity A.sum + 1
Non-transaction: update Entity A.sum + 1
Transaction: save Entity A
Non-transaction: save Entity A
Transaction: transaction done.
Non-transaction: done.

Naturally, you always want to use a transaction to update a field, but I am trying to understand what would actually happen if the above took place.
Would the locks placed on the entity in the transaction prevent or fail the read/write operations on that same entity not in a transaction?
Would the non-transaction update mess with the transaction update and cause the sum to revert to what it was originally?

If you have a look to this doc, you should understand the process. In fact, the transaction process do not lock the row or the table (as relational database do) but implement optimistic lock
In fact, in your line 1 (and 2 also), the API will return a ETAG value. This value is sent when you "commit" your transaction (line 7).

If the etag is the same in the database, that means no update on the data and the data are saved
If the etag value is different in the database, that means an update occur while you processing/building your transaction. Your commit fail and you have to handle this case

You can see other mode exist like pessimistic, but the principle is still the same (only timing change).
